# Updating Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, time, auto-update, getelementbyid

I'm trying to create an updating clock in Javascript. Everything is working correctly as I step through the debugger, except that it's not actually updating the span. Any ideas why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// The following line of code is in a setInterval() 
// time is set correctly, according to my debugger
 document.getElementById('clock').value = time;
}
</script>
<span id="clock">This should update
</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `value` to `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = time;
```

`value` is only a valid attribute for form elements like `input` or `option`.

Answer (score -2):

Also, to have it refresh (if you are doing a clock), use window.setTimeout;

```
window.setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = 'XYZ'; }, 500);
```

500 is millisecond value.

Comment: Brian, your answer still includes his error. He also states he is already using `setInterval` though the partial pasting of the code is confusing.

Comment: My statement was an add on to the existing answer, hence the ALSO part of my comment.  He said setInterval, I did setTimeout in mine.

Comment: @Brian `getElementById('clock').value` is invalid code. You can't post broken code and expect it to help the OP out.